# What does "client pitch" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Your capacity for empathy, gratitude, and generosity can be cultivated
>   by engaging in simple social behaviors whenever the opportunity
>   presents itself: a team meeting, a **client pitch** or negotiation, a
>   360-degree feedback session.

I searched the online dictionaries, and [client](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/client) means:

- someone who pays for services or advice from a professional person or organization.
- someone who buys something from a seller SYN CUSTOMER.

And for [pitch](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/pitch)(BUSINESS DEALS):

- to try to persuade someone to do business with you, buy something etc
  pitch for business/contracts/custom etc

But I can't understand  meaning of the phrase "a client pitch" exactly.

So, Could you explain it to me? Is a session? Or, is a kind of presentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A **pitch** is not just the persuasion, it is also the word for the presentation itself. So a 'client pitch' is 'a presentation to persuade someone who pays for services'

Generally these are potential clients, people who still need to be persuaded to become clients.